# Celery worker stops consuming from a specific queue while it consumes from other queues

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I am using rabbitmq as broker, there is a strange behaviour that is happening in my production environment only. Randomly sometimes my celery stops consuming messages from a queue, while it consumes from other queues.

This leads to pileup on messages in queue, if i restart my celeryd everything starts to work fine.

"/var/logs/celeryd/worker" does not indicate any error. I am not even sure where to start looking as i am new to python/django.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: anything of note in /var/log/rabbitmq ? Maybe try turning up your logging verbosity for celery. Maybe the db is choking out, are your tasks writing to a DB? Can we see some related lines from settings.py for your config and/or the code that you're using for proccessing the queue?

Comment: What are the priorities for various queues in your celery? Does it ever resumes the queue you are complaining about?

Comment: @chris : The rabbitmq logs are normal ::

Comment: The DB is working fine cause there other tasks from different queues are picked up and are written to same DB.
<br/>
`class OrderInfoConsumerStep(ConsumerStep):<br/>
    queue = Queue(settings.QUEUES)<br/>
    def get_consumers(self, channel):<br/>
        return [Consumer(channel, queues=[self.queue, ],<br/>
                         callbacks=[self.handle_message, ], accept=['json', ])]<br/>
    def handle_message(self, body, message):<br/>
        data = json.loads(body)//storeData<br/>
            message.ack()<br/>
celery_app.steps['consumer'].add(OrderInfoConsumerStep)<br/>`

Comment: @Rajesh : it resumes once i restart my celery. We did not restart once for an hour and it did not consume from the queue for an hour.

Also the priorities are same for all queues, there is no preference to the queues, however the other queue which does not get stuck has more messages published to it than the one that is getting blocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem in my code,

So in one of my task i was opening a connection to parse using urllib3 that was getting hung.

After moving out that portion in async task, things are working fine now.

Comment: Why was it getting hung? I am facing a similar issue

Comment: For me, the problem was that eventually all workers were getting blocked due to external calls getting hung. Check for anything that might be blocking the workers forever. I would suggest putting enough logs to get to the code that is not executing.